# Next.js Redirects: redirects key in next.config.js vs. redirect object in getServerSideProps()

Tags: next.js

Let's just say I want to redirect my `index` page to the `about` page in Next.js. It seems like I have 2 options:

##### 1. Adding the `redirects` key in `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/about',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

##### 2. Returning the `redirect` object inside the `getServerSideProps()` function

```js
// pages/index.js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/about',
      permanent: true,
    },
  };
};
```

What is the difference between these 2 options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logic, they're the same in terms of functionality, but `redirect` on your page `pages/index.js` will have more flexibility and more customization. For example, you want to redirect to another page conditionally like below

```
// pages/index.js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const value = true; //receive data from APIs

  //if value is true, redirect to `/help` instead of `/about`
  if(value) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/help',
        permanent: true,
      },
    };
  }

  //TODO: You can add your logic here before redirection

  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/about',
      permanent: true,
    },
  };
};
```

You cannot achieve that logic with `redirects()` under `next.config.js`. You can imagine that it's like configurations being only applied once without the complicated logic requirement.

You can consider these use cases:

- If you don't want to have complicated routing logic and just use them as one-time setups - Use `redirects()` in `next.config.js`
- If you have some logic to handle routings in pages and it's relied on external resources - Use `redirect` in pages themselves